# Глобальная модель в Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

Написал сервис в котором задается и возвращается переменная `counter`:

```
.factory('CounterNotificationService', function() {

            var counter = {
                feed : 0,
                messages : 0,
                notifications : 0
            };

            return {

                getCounter: function() {
                    return counter;
                },

                setCounterInc: function(field, type) {
                    counter[field] = (type == 'inc') ? counter[field]++ : counter[field]--;
                },

                setCounterValue: function(field, value) {
                    counter[field] = value;
                }
            };
        })
```

Соответственно в нужных мне контроллерах вызываю этот сервис:

```
/* test */
        .controller('Tst1Controller', ['$scope','$http','$sce','CounterNotificationService', function($scope, $http, $sce, CounterNotificationService) {
            CounterNotificationService.setCounterValue('messages', 6);
            $scope.tst = CounterNotificationService.getCounter();
        }])

        .controller('Tst2Controller', ['$scope','$http','$sce','CounterNotificationService', function($scope, $http, $sce, CounterNotificationService) {
            //CounterNotificationService.setCounterValue('messages', 4);
            //$scope.tst = CounterNotificationService.getCounter();
        }])
```

В итоге, я хочу добиться того, чтобы в любом контроллере после обновления значений `counter` в сервисе - это значение заносилось в `$scope.tst` и обновлялось на странице, в любом другом контроллере как глобальная переменная.

Comment: Ну, так и что не работает?

Comment: Проблема в том, что когда я беру значение `counter` в другом контроллере и присваивают переменной `$scope.tst` в этом контроллере - то в шаблоне` {{tst}}` не меняется.

Comment: А не пробовали использовать $rootScope.  Он «глобален» везде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо давать ссылку на объект, в таком случае все изменения буду привязаны к объекту:

```
angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('First', ['$scope', 'dataService', function($scope, dataService){
    $scope.data = dataService.data;
}])
.controller('Second', function($scope, dataService){
    $scope.data = dataService.data;
})
.factory('dataService', function(){
    var service = {
        data: {
            value : 'default service value'
        }
    };

    return service;
});
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/n0f59zua/)

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, а чем ваш вариант отличается от варианта автора вопроса? Разве CounterNotificationService.getCounter() у него в примере не возвращает ссылку на объект counter объявленный в factory?

Comment: @nikita в моем примере я возращаю объект внутри объекта, в примере автора возращаеться только объект

Comment: я и пытаюсь понять -  в чем принципиальная разница? http://jsfiddle.net/n0f59zua/1/ - я добавил вариант автора и все тоже работает, насколько я понимаю?